# Get a list of attachment ID's for each Work Item on VSTS

Tags: rest, tfs, azure-devops, attachment

Was wondering if anyone has managed to achieve this. I am currently on VSTS 2017 (Version 15.117.27024.0) where it has been troublesome to find any documentation on what version of REST Api I should be using.

If you require any other information, feel free to let me know.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#api-and-tfs-version-mapping

Answer (score 0):

> Get a list of attachment ID's for each Work Item on VSTS

You asked the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56656447/how-to-download-all-attachments-from-vsts) before but not give any feedback.

To make sure this issue clear. I will answer it again.

To get the attachment id you can use the Get Work Item API with `$expand=all`:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{workItemID}?api-version=5.0&$expand=all
```

Then you will get the attachment ID in the url in the relations section (I use the tool postman):

[image]

So, you can get the attachment ID is `acd5af0e-c015-4e8f-8354-a6858582deb2`.

BTW, you could download the download the attachment use the API:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/attachments/acd5af0e-c015-4e8f-8354-a6858582deb2?api-version=5.1-preview.3
```

Ticket: [Attachments - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

Hope this helps.